# this/self in es6 class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When I call a method of an es6 class from a callback I can no longer refer to `this` as my object:

```
class store{
  constructor(){
    this.value = 10;
  };

  printValue(self){
    console.log(this);
    console.log(self);//the value that I want print
  };
};

class undefinedClass{
  constructor(store){
    this.store = store;
  };

  storeQuery(){
    let ff = this.store.printValue;
    setTimeout(ff, 300, this.store);
  };
};

let i = new store();
let b = new undefinedClass(i);
b.storeQuery();
```

When I call b.storeQuery() tha value that I want print is the second one.
Is there a more elegant way for do that?

Comment: You do not seem to be passing the `self` parameter into `printValue`... what is it supposed to be equal to?

Comment: See also [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @alex say, with a `.bind`

The documentation is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```js
class store{
  constructor(){
    this.value = 10;
  };

  printValue(){
   
    console.log(this.value);//the value that I want print
  };
};

class undefinedClass{
  constructor(store){
    this.store = store;
  };

  storeQuery(){
    setTimeout(this.store.printValue.bind(this.store), 300);
  };
};


let i = new store();
let b = new undefinedClass(i);

 
b.storeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use an object's function reference in JavaScript, it will lose its ThisBinding being set to that object.

You can the ThisBinding to anything using `Function.prototype.bind()`.

In this case you would use something like `ff.bind(this.store)`.

Comment: alex -- please see my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722798/this-self-in-es6-class#comment61030536_36722798 How do you address that?

Comment: Or use an arrow function. `printValue` expects an argument anyway.